# XCode simulator is not displaying latest changes

Tags: ios, xcode4.5, simulator

I am creating an app in XCode 4.5. My problem is that I am running app in simulator but it is not showing recent changes. On resetting `Content and Settings` from `iOS simulator` option it shows latest output. But, if I close simulator and ran app again, it again shows old output.
Can anyone have idea, what is behind that and how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Which version of the iOS-Simulator are you running?

Comment: it is iPhone 5.1 simulator.

Comment: quit the simulator and launch it again

Answer (score 2):

try deleting the app from the simulator (like you would do it on the iPhone), then rerun your app from xcode

Comment: I have tried this too and even reset everything from Content and Settings option of iOS simulator.But, this didn't solve my problem.

Comment: have you tried deleting your simulator folder? `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/` (will be recreated automatically)

Answer (score 2):

What I do when this happens:

1) delete the app from the simulator

2) run Project>Clean

3) run Project>Clean Build Folder (CMD + Shift + Option + k)

4) manually delete the Derived Data folder for the app (you'll find this under Organizer>Projects)

You may not need all of these steps every time.

Answer (score 2):

If you are working with Ionic, then Sorry to say But this is a issue, that ionic changes don't show changes.

For Now, you have to remove ios Platform form your Ionic Project and Add again the ios Platform.

Working for me...

Answer (score 0):

Just rename your storyboard and select it from Project - General this works for me.

If it doesn't work delete the app in the simulator and try this again this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting Build Directory from your project and then clean the project and build it again

Answer (score 0):

If this happens when using Capacitor with Xcode, try this:

1. `ionic build`
2. `npx cap sync` or  `npx cap copy`
3. rerun the app in the simulator (press the 'play' buton again)

Note:
The `sync` command updates dependencies, and copies any web assets to your project.
The `copy` command copies web assets only, which is faster if you know you don’t need to update native dependencies.

(https://capacitorjs.com/docs/ios)